# SVN on Ubuntu with Lighttpd web server?

Tags: svn, lighttpd

I need to install svn on Ubuntu 10.03 and Ubuntu 9.04. On both servers I use lighttpd.

I found some tutorials on internet explaining which packages to install with Apache, but i actually need lighttpd.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old post, but it [seems to answer your question directly](http://forum.lighttpd.net/topic/59).  Basically, it looks like there's no lighttpd equivalent of `mod_dav_svn`, which is how Apache allows you to communicate with svn through HTTP.

So the answer is no.  Basically, the only solution that will get you as close to what you want, is to *proxy* lighttpd to an internally run Apache server.  Keep in mind, this still requires that you use both lighttpd and Apache simultaneously.

Comment: So to summarize, I cannot use svnserve with Lighttpd ? Anyway I've just realized that I just need svn to import some repositories, and I don't need to setup a repository on my server..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this info](http://longspine.com/how-to/install-lighttpd-and-subversion-on-debian-lenny/) helps, as Ubuntu and Debian are somewhat similar.

Comment: Thanks. From the tutorial I can see that lighttpd and svn are not related at all. The tutorial first explains how to install lighttpd (I already have it) and then svn. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is because I found tutorials for Apache+svn requiring specific apache+svn packages.

Comment: Unfortunately, the listed guide uses `ssh` to communicate with svn, not `mod_dav_svn` (which is used by Apache).